# HTML Table search on the third column using JavaScript

Tags: asp.net-core, html-table

I am trying to search any employee status  exist with IsProtected in the tabl empTable. if any row exist , then the variable  ProtectedIsfound  must be true

```
    <table id="empTable" >
    <tr>
        <th>
            Employee Name
        </th>
        <th>
            Designation
        </th>
     <th>
            Status
        </th>
        
    </tr>
for (i = 0; i < Model.attendanceLogList.Count; i++)
{
    <tr>
               <td>@Model.attendanceLogList[i].EmployeeName</td>
               <td>@Model.attendanceLogList[i].Designation</td>
           <td>@Model.attendanceLogList[i].IsProtected</td>  // it is boolean in model
       
      </tr>
}


</table>
<script>
    var ProtectedIsfound = True // if any record exist with the value is Protected in the column status in the table empTable 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to search any employee status exist with IsProtected in
> the tabl empTable. if any row exist , then the variable
> ProtectedIsfound must be true

Do you mean for each row, if the IsProtected is true, the ProtectedIsFound must be true? If that is the case, please refer to the following methods:

1. Using JavaScript or JQuery method: Loop through the table rows and cells and check if the IsProtected is true, then, based on the result to change the ProtectedIsFound value.

   ```
    @*JQuery reference*@
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var ProtectedIsfound = false // default value. 
        //JavaScript method:
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
            //loop through the tr and td, then based on the IsProtected value to change the ProtectedIsFound value.
            var trlist = document.getElementById("empTable").getElementsByTagName("tr");
            for (var i = 1; i < trlist.length; i++) {
                if (trlist[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2].innerText.toLowerCase() == "true") { 
                    ProtectedIsfound = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            console.log(ProtectedIsfound);
        });
        //JQuery script
        $(function () {
            $("#empTable").find("tr:not(:first-child)").each(function (index, item) {
                if ($(item).find("td")[2].innerText.toLowerCase() == "true") {
                    ProtectedIsfound = true;
                    return false;
                }
            });
            console.log(ProtectedIsfound);
        });
    </script>
   ```
2. Using Where and Select statement, code as below:

   ```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var ProtectedIsfound = @Model.attendanceLogList.Where(c => c.IsProtected ==true).Select(c=>c).ToList().Count > 0 ? true : false;
        console.log(ProtectedIsfound); 
    </script>
   ```

The Html page elements as below (**Asp.net core Razor page application**):

```
    @page
    @model RazorWebApplication5.Pages.HtmlTableModel
    @{ 
    }
        <table id="empTable">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Employee Name
                </th>
                <th>
                    Designation
                </th>
                <th>
                    Status
                </th>

            </tr>
            @for (var i = 0; i < Model.attendanceLogList.Count; i++)
            {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@Model.attendanceLogList[i].EmployeeName</td>
                        <td>@Model.attendanceLogList[i].Designation</td>
                        <td>@Model.attendanceLogList[i].IsProtected</td>  @*// it is boolean in model*@

                    </tr>
            }
        </table>
```

.cshtml.cs file:

```
    public class HtmlTableModel : PageModel
    {
        public List<AttendanceLog> attendanceLogList { get; set; }
        public void OnGet()
        {
            //initial data
            attendanceLogList = new List<AttendanceLog>()
            {
                new AttendanceLog(){ EmployeeName="Tom", Designation="A", IsProtected=false},
                new AttendanceLog(){ EmployeeName="Jack", Designation="B", IsProtected=false},
                new AttendanceLog(){ EmployeeName="Lucy", Designation="CC", IsProtected=true},
                new AttendanceLog(){ EmployeeName="Daive", Designation="D", IsProtected=false},
                new AttendanceLog(){ EmployeeName="Hanke", Designation="E", IsProtected=false}
            };
        }
    }

    public class AttendanceLog
    {
        public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
        public string Designation { get; set; }
        public bool IsProtected { get; set; }
    }
```

Test result:

[image]

Comment: When I apply linq query in Javascript the following error is being showed System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Where[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)

Comment: In my above sample, I was using asp.net core Razor page, I have posted the whole code, please check it. According to the error message, it seems that in the JavaScript script, the "Model" is null. If you are not using asp.net core Razor page, try to use the JavaScript/JQuery method to loop through the table and change the ProtectedIsFound  value.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change the for loop into:
   "for (i = 0; i <= Model.attendanceLogList.Count; i++)", it should count up to the total number of the List.
2. Not sure what library you're using in the script, but instead of:
   var ProtectedIsfound = True, it should state
3. You need a dedicated class name to the  so you can refer it in the script

"bool ProtectedIsFound:"
It should be set to true by default.

```
foreach(emp in Model.attendanceLogList){

  if (emp.IsProtected){
      {here you will need to append the value in the Status column}
      return true; }
  else
return;
}
```

Comment: This is a very blunt logic, but you will need to include a database and to pull and write the data using a Stored Procedure(is one way), so the status can be saved somewhere.